# Ipv4 is not in private range ip when i connect to a vpn?

Tags: networking, vpn, ipv4

As far as i understand when you connect to a vpn server it should give you private ip (192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255 or 172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255 or 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255) but when i connected to a vpn in cmd ipconfig my ipv4 is starting with 100.127.x.x which is not in private range ip what im missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing two things:

#### 1. Private addresses are not mandatory

No type of network is ever required to use private IP addresses. The primary reason we use private address ranges is because we don't have enough public (i.e. normal) IPv4 addresses to spare. (Hence the move to IPv6.)

If the network's operator has a sufficiently large public IP address block, they can use it for their LAN, for their VPN – for anything they want, not necessarily for WAN connections.

(The term 'private' in "Virtual Private Network" has nothing to do with private-use IP address ranges; it's just named that because it lets you connect to someone's *private network*, literally.)

#### 2. The address you see isn't actually public

Aside from the three private ranges you mention, there is a fourth: **100.64.0.0/10**, meant for use by ISPs rather than end-networks, but otherwise still the same type of "private-use" address block. (See [RFC 6598](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6598) for more information).

The /10 expands to 100.64.0.0 – 100.127.255.255, and your address 100.127.x.x is within this range.

Answer (score 0):

100.127.x.x is part of the 100.64.0.0/10 address block, which contains all IPv4 addresses in the range 100.64.0.0–100.127.255.255.

This range *is* reserved for private IP addresses, though you probably see it let than the 10.x.x.x and 192.x.x.x ranges.

Specifically, the 100.64.0.0/10 range is used as a private address range for [carrier-grade NAT](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT?wprov=sfla1).